# cassandra backup like mysql

Tags: cassandra, backup, restore

I am learning Cassandra now-a-days, i have successfully backup and restore tables or keyspace mentioned in this [URL.](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_snapshot_restore_t.html)

But i am looking for following options

> 1)Take complete backup of a keyspace at different location other then mentioned directory in cassandra.yaml. -t option create directory in snapshot folder not different HDD location.
>
> 2) Or backup/restore procedure same like mysql.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options...for small amounts of data, you can use COPY to backup / restore from csv:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html

For larger stuff, you've got the right link. You essentially take a snapshot (which puts it in the folder you mention), and then use something like tar to zip the files and output to a different directory. This is what we're doing in production... we clear the previous snapshot, take a snapshot and tar the folder to a network backup.

Comment: Its mean you go to each table in kekpace, tar it and copy it to some other network location.

Comment: yes...though with some clever clever use of find, etc. and some regex you can specify all (or a few keyspaces) and do the tarring in one go.

Comment: This is the script I'm currently using. Not perfect (probably) but is getting the job done :)

https://github.com/heartysoft/puppet-cassandra/blob/master/files/cassandra_backup.sh

Comment: Good idea to provide your script.  This is pretty much what we do, too.  Nicely done!